# Reading memory from an application I do not own in C++ (example in vb.net)

Tags: c++, vb.net

A couple of months ago, before I started learning C++, I made an application in VB.net that reads memory from an external program. This could be anything, from notepad to windows media player etc.

I have been trying to find a way to do the exact same thing in C++, but to my suprise I can't find anything straightforward on the subject. All google comes up with is threads on several forums, where the general response is "Windows doesn't allow you to read from memory you do not own". But if it works in VB.net, it can work in C++ too.

Don't be fooled by the amount of code, it's extremely straightforward.

**Declarations**

```
Imports System.Math
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

//Guess what this does ;D
Private Declare Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Integer, ByVal bInheritHandle As Integer, ByVal dwProcessId As Integer) As Integer

//Allows us to read a float from the memory.
Private Declare Function ReadProcessMemory Lib "kernel32" _
Alias "ReadProcessMemory" (ByVal hProcess As Integer, _
                           ByVal lpBaseAddress As Integer, _
                           ByRef lpBuffer As Single, _
                           ByVal nSize As Integer, _
                           ByRef lpNumberOfBytesWritten As Integer) As Integer

//Allows us to read an integer or string from the memory. String will require a loop.
Private Declare Function ReadProcessMemoryInt Lib "kernel32" _
    Alias "ReadProcessMemory" (ByVal hProcess As Integer, _
                               ByVal lpBaseAddress As Integer, _
                               ByRef lpBuffer As Integer, _
                               ByVal nSize As Integer, _
                               ByRef lpNumberOfBytesWritten As Integer) As Integer

//Allows us to find a memory address when provided with a pointer and offsets
Private Declare Function ReadProcessMemoryPointer Lib "kernel32" Alias "ReadProcessMemory" ( _
   ByVal hProcess As IntPtr, _
   ByVal lpBaseAddress As IntPtr, _
   <Out()> ByVal lpBuffer() As Byte, _
   ByVal dwSize As Integer, _
   ByRef lpNumberOfBytesRead As Integer) As Boolean

//Close a handle
Private Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hObject As Integer) As Integer

//Shortcut to get read & write access to an application
Const PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = &H1F0FFF
```

**Functions using these Declarations**

```
//Function to get string from memory
Public Function memstring(ByVal address As Long, ByVal length As Int32, ByVal processHandle As IntPtr)
    Dim stringinmemory As Long
    Dim ret1 As Byte() = Nothing
    Dim tStr(length) As Char
    Dim retStr As String = ""
    For i As Int32 = 0 To length - 1
        ReadProcessMemoryInt(processHandle, address + i, stringinmemory, 1, 0)
        ret1 = BitConverter.GetBytes(stringinmemory)
        tStr(i) = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ret1) : retStr += tStr(i)
    Next
    Return retStr
End Function

//Function to get float from memory. I don't know what those comments are all about, it's been a long time since I used this code.
Public Function memfloat(ByVal address As Long, ByVal processHandle As IntPtr)
    Dim floatvalueinmemory As Single
    ReadProcessMemory(processHandle, address, floatvalueinmemory, 4, 0)
    //Floatvalueinmemory didn't give the desired result, so going to try to TryParse
    Dim letstryagain As Single
    Single.TryParse(floatvalueinmemory, letstryagain)
    //Unfortunately returns the same result as floatvalueinmemory did
    Return CStr(letstryagain)
End Function

//Function to get int from memory
Public Function memInt(ByVal address As Long, ByVal processHandle As IntPtr)
    Dim intvalueinmemory As Integer
    ReadProcessMemoryInt(processHandle, address, intvalueinmemory, 4, 0)
    Return CStr(intvalueinmemory)
End Function

//Function to find a memory address when provided with a pointer and offsets
Private Function FindAddress(ByVal pHandle As IntPtr, ByVal BaseAddress As IntPtr, ByVal StaticPointer As IntPtr, ByVal Offsets() As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    // Create a buffer that is 4 bytes on a 32-bit system or 8 bytes on a 64-bit system.
    Dim tmp(IntPtr.Size - 1) As Byte
    Dim Address As IntPtr = BaseAddress
    // We must check for 32-bit vs 64-bit.
    If IntPtr.Size = 4 Then
        Address = New IntPtr(Address.ToInt32 + StaticPointer.ToInt32)
    Else
        Address = New IntPtr(Address.ToInt64 + StaticPointer.ToInt64)
    End If
    // Loop through each offset to find the address
    For i As Integer = 0 To Offsets.Length - 1
        ReadProcessMemoryPointer(pHandle, Address, tmp, IntPtr.Size, 0)
        If IntPtr.Size = 4 Then
            Address = BitConverter.ToInt32(tmp, 0) + Offsets(i).ToInt32()
        Else
            Address = BitConverter.ToInt64(tmp, 0) + Offsets(i).ToInt64()
        End If
    Next
    Return Address
End Function
```

**Example usage**

```
Sub somesub()
    //Get process handle.
    Dim myProcesses As Process() = Process.GetProcessesByName("SomeProgram")
    Dim processHandle As IntPtr = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, myProcesses(0).Id)

    //We'll need the base address when we need to find an address through pointers.
    BaseAddressSet = myProcesses(0).MainModule.BaseAddress

    //Get float from memory.
    somefloat = memfloat(&H12980D8, processHandle)

    //Get string from memory.
    somestring = memstring(&H12955E0, 15, processHandle)

    //Get float from memory through a pointer.
    Dim sptr As IntPtr = &HF28EE4 //Static pointer for float address we want to get
    Dim Offsets As IntPtr() = {&H61C, &H19C, &H2AC, &HDC, &H198} //Offsets for float address we want to get
    Dim addr As IntPtr = FindAddress(processHandle, BaseAddressSet, sptr, Offsets)
    somefloat = memfloat(addr, processHandle)

    //All done.
    CloseHandle(processHandle)
 End Sub
```

**Footer**

```
Partial Public Class NativeMethods
    <DllImport("user32.dll")> _
    Public Shared Function ReadProcessMemory(ByVal hProcess As System.IntPtr, ByVal lpBaseAddress As IntPtr, ByVal lpBuffer As System.IntPtr, ByVal nSize As UInteger, ByVal lpNumberOfBytesRead As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function
End Class
```

Please advise on how to do this in C++, or where I can learn how to do this.

Comment: you basically just call the same runtime functions as you do from vb, it is just a matter that you need to a lot more manual labor like loading dlls/GetProcAddress etc.

Comment: @AndersK so basically I need to find a way to get access to kernel32 lib and user32 dll in C++, so I can exploit the same functions I used in vb.net? Sorry if this is a beginner question, but I have never had to deal with this in C++ before.

Comment: It's actually quite a bit *less* manual labor in C++. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a small program to search for a specified string in the memory blocks of a specified target process.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

template <class outIter>
void find_locs(HANDLE process, std::string const &pattern, outIter output) {

    unsigned char *p = NULL;
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION info;

    for ( p = NULL;
        VirtualQueryEx(process, p, &info, sizeof(info)) == sizeof(info);
        p += info.RegionSize ) 
    {
        std::vector<char> buffer;
        std::vector<char>::iterator pos;

        if (info.State == MEM_COMMIT && 
            (info.Type == MEM_MAPPED || info.Type == MEM_PRIVATE)) 
        {
            DWORD bytes_read;
            buffer.resize(info.RegionSize);
            ReadProcessMemory(process, p, &buffer[0], info.RegionSize, &bytes_read);
            buffer.resize(bytes_read);
            for ( pos = buffer.begin();
                buffer.end()!=(pos=std::search(pos, buffer.end(), pattern.begin(), pattern.end()));
                ++pos)
            {
                *output++ = p+(pos-buffer.begin());
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <process ID> <pattern>", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    int pid;
    sscanf(argv[1], "%i", &pid);

    std::string pattern(argv[2]);

    HANDLE process = OpenProcess( 
        PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, 
        false,
        pid);

    find_locs(process, pattern, 
        std::ostream_iterator<void *>(std::cout, "\n"));

    return 0;
}
```

To build it, you need to specify the correct library for the linker:

```
cl search_proc.cpp kernel32.lib
```

Comment: What exactly is a "pattern". I found the notepad.exe PID, 4780. So I tried; `readmemory_test_2 4780 &H1F5E5F0` and also `readmemory_test_2 4780 01F5E5F0` but nothing is happening. Is there maybe a book or online tutorial/article/whatever that will have a practical use for this kind of stuff? I don't really want to trial-and-error something as complex as this, and since I don't even know what a memory 'pattern' is...

Comment: @natli: In this case, it's just a sequence of bytes it'll look for in the memory space of the specified process. Also note that I originally wrote this for a fairly specific purpose -- the requirement for committed and (mapped or private) memory may not fit your needs. In short, although it'll compile and run as-is, it probably won't do much that's useful -- it's mostly to read the source code to see how to use ReadProcessMemory from C++.