# How would I search the memory of a process for a specific string?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, memory-address

I'm interested in the basics. I have no idea where to begin with this. I've created this test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char* test = "TEST04560";
    getchar();
    printf("%s\n", test);
}
```

The goal is to locate the memory address of "TEST04560" using an external program. I know how to use `ReadProcessMemory` and `WriteProcessMemory` but I don't know how to go about searching for a specific string in a program's memory. Any tips in the right direction are greatly appreciated.

Comment: it's not clear what exactly you want. you can't just search process memory, let alone from external process. Process memory accessible to you may not be contiguous and/readable. Or do you want to know the address of variable `test` ?

Comment: Well of course you can search an external processes memory, if my understanding is correct. OllyDbg, IDA, and Cheat Engine are examples. I want to know the address at which `TEST04560` is stored, which the variable `test` points to. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Not quite a duplicate question, but my answer should get you on the right track: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9022929/179910

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What operating system? Most all OSes have some sort of "debugging" facility that allows you to observe/modify other processes (if you have permissions, of course).

On Linux, this is [`ptrace`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace).

On Windows, there is [`ReadProcessMemory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553.aspx), and [friends](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679303.aspx).

And for searching data of any type, there is [`memcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcmp/). If you know how to use `ReadProcessMemory`, you certainly are familiar with this function.

Comment: Oh, my appologies. I didn't know I had to tell him how to use `memcmp` to, for Christ's sake. Certainly didn't think it warranted a downvote. Seems quite odd that someone claims to know how to use a debug API but not how to search memory for a string.

Comment: Windows 7. Right, but I don't know what the accessible memory range for a process is. I know there are regions that will crash my program if I attempt to read them.

Comment: @John, well then maybe that is the question you should be asking. Just saying. If you want good answers, ask good questions.

Comment: You can't crash your program by simply reading memory from another app, assuming correct privileges.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I'm not sure which API calls to use, but there are a plethora of [Memory Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366781(v=vs.85).aspx) functions. You'll need to use those to find out the memory mappings of the target process. Play around with OllyDbg or Immunity, and see what they can know about a process. Then do some research and see what it takes to get that info. Eventually you'll be able to figure out where the `.text` (code) and `.data` sections are mapped in.

Comment: You can enumerate all the loaded modules (and get their starting address)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682621(v=vs.85).aspx

Afterwhich I recommend reading the documentation on the Windows PE format. Then you can manually find the sections and compare byte by byte. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463119.aspx

Comment: @TheStrve I'd thought about mentioning the PE header - but does the in-memory header tell you where the sections were *actually* loaded? Or is it merely a copy of the on-disk header?