# Can I use ReadProcessMemory to read the memory of a thread

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to read the memory of a thread in a process for a string, and I was wondering if it's possible to use ReadProcessMemory() to read the memory of the thread.
I'm fairly new to the Win32 API so forgive my noobish-nes.

Comment: Everything that executes on Windows is “in a thread”.  Is the thread in question a thread in the process that would be calling that function, or is it a thread in some other process?

Comment: @Sneftel it's a thread in another process. I want to find a string in that thread

Comment: All threads in a process share the same memory space. The only thread-specific storage is the call stacks (and other thread-local data), but they are still in the same space.

Comment: @jonathankachlon You can't locate objects by thread, only by memory address. Multiple threads could be sharing access to an object. If you have the memory address of the string you are interested in, then you can read it with `ReadProcessMemory()` (if you have permissions to access the process for reading, that is).

Answer (score 0):

According to the Doc: [About Processes and Threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/about-processes-and-threads)

A thread is the entity within a process that can be scheduled for execution. All threads of a process share its virtual address space and system resources.

And in my opinion, you could search the memory of a process for a specific string instead of search the memory of a thread. If so, you could use [ReadProcessMemory function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-readprocessmemory) to realize it.(The entire area to be read must be accessible, and if it is not accessible, the function fails.)

I suggest you could refer to the thread:[How would I search the memory of a process for a specific string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14393267/how-would-i-search-the-memory-of-a-process-for-a-specific-string)